# Why my compiler doesn't compile matrix?

Tags: matrices

I am still a beginner. But, I'm very sure my writing is correct

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{matrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{matrix}
\end{document}
```

But it doesn't compile on my laptop, please help?

Comment: you need `\usepackage{amsmath}`

Comment: And, LaTeX needs to be in math mode when it encounters the `matrix` environment.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm very sure my writing is correct

The code in your test document is not wrong *per se*. However, it is *incomplete* in two crucial aspects. To get the test document to compile, you need to

- put the `matrix` environment into math mode. A display-math group, initiated by `\[` and terminated by `\]`, would seem appropriate; in addition, you need to
- load a LaTeX package that defines an environment called `matrix`; the `amsmath` package would be a leading candidate.

In short, try to compile

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % <-- new (amsmath defines 'matrix' environment)
\begin{document}
\[ % <-- new
\begin{matrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{matrix}
\] % <-- new
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, it's working

Comment: But if i want to attach bracket why is still not working \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\begin{document}
\left[
\begin{matrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{matrix}
\right]
\end{document}

Comment: @MohammadFerryHusnilArif like `matrix` `\left..\right` is a math mode construct so needs to be inside the `\[....\]` math display. (but it is better to simply change `matrix` to `bmatrix` rather than use `\left\[` here.